# Why does Unity think my RectTransform has changed?

Tags: unity, c#

I am working with UI.  I want to know when my `RectTransform` changes its position.  I am using `transform.hasChanged`:

```
void Update()
{
    if (transform.hasChanged)
    {
        Debug.Log("Updated Position");
        transform.hasChanged = false;
    }
}
```

However, it thinks it has always changed.  "Updated Position" is constantly printing out.  If I remove and then readd the component while in play mode, the issue resolves itself.  However, I don't want to have to do this, as it is very hacky.

I could just throw a bunch of if statements in there to check, but I'd prefer to make use of the build in `transform.hasChanged` property.

How can I check to see if my `RectTransform` has changed its position efficiently and elegantly?

Comment: Is the canvas that the `RectTransform` exists on parented to anything that moves?

Comment: @Coburn nope. its not

Comment: You're going to need to provide a picture with the heirarchy of your objects and a picture of the other components on this `GameObject` with the `RectTransform` and the `MonoBehaviour` that does the printing and stuff. I made a simple project with the code provided and it doesn't constantly print so something else is going on here that's causing this to happen.

Comment: @Coburn some unity bug apparently. they already have a tracker on it. problem fixed itself.  thanks!!

Comment: @Evorlor I am having the same problem, which version of Unity is this bug fixed? I am using Unity Version 2018.1.0f2.

Comment: @azemda Sorry, but I do not remember.  However, Unity 2018 was not released at the time I made this post, so it should have been fixed unless it regressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Unity bug, and has since been fixed.  Update your version of Unity to resolve.